# How do I delete one item in a CheckBoxList which is bound in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

This is my binding code:

```
string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBC"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from stud_table", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds);
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds;
            CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Name";
            CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "Rollno";
            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
                con.Open();
```

Button code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0;i<CheckBoxList1.Items.Count ;i++)
    {
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
 }
```

If I select the item and I click delete button, it should remove from the database and in the screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, hope this helps:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private readonly string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBC"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsToDelete = new ListItemCollection(); 

        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
                itemsToDelete.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (ListItem item in itemsToDelete)
        {
            //Assuming your id column is Rollno
            DeleteFromDB(item.Value);
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM stud_table", con))
            {
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds;
                CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Name";
                CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "Rollno";
                CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void DeleteFromDB(string rollNo)
    {
        int id = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(rollNo, out id))
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
            {
                con.Open();
                string commandText = String.Format("DELETE FROM stud_table WHERE Rollno={0}", id);
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Place a brake point on DeleteFromDB and debug your code.Does the rollNo passed through to the delete statement exist in the database

Comment: no it is not not going through delete statement after if condition in DeleteFromDB it is going to button2

Comment: What datatype is rollNo in the database?If it's a string/varchar/nvarchar remove the if statement and int id=0 and change the delete statement to be string commandText = String.Format("DELETE FROM stud_table WHERE Rollno={0}", rollNo);